# Local caching of blob (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, caching, blob

I'm dealing with a scenario where users in the hundreds access to videos stored on a web server on a regular basis. Two conditions are mandatory
1 - Videos must be 100% downloaded before playback is allowed
2 - The last played video(s) should be accessible offline

To begin with, I am providing the Video element not with a static source, but rather with a blob, like follows (webkit only for now)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
xhr.open('GET', 'http://someurl/content.mp4', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) 
{
 if (this.status == 200) 
 {
  var myBlob = this.response;
  var data = (window.webkitURL ? webkitURL : URL).createObjectURL(myBlob);
  var video = document.getElementById("player");
  video.src = data;
  video.play();
 }
}
xhr.send();
```

Now, the question: how can I locally cache the above blob? How can I check for its presence in the local machine's cache and retrieve it rather than download it from the web server again?

Thanks

r.

Comment: For local storage of large amounts of data you'll probably need to use **[_IndexedDB_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)**, more specifically [**this example**](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/)

Comment: Thanks Paul, great solution - straight to the point. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Update: unfortunately, looks like both Chrome and Firefox took a step back in supporting blobs in IndexedDB. Everything works well until it's time to add the record, then I get the following: Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store currently does not support blob values. A workaround could be converting the Blob to Base64... but how?

Comment: :/ y u no support _Blob_ this way, _Chrome_? .. A quick google search should give you a few ways to convert blob to base64, the easiest way is via _FileReader/data URLs_ (remember to trim off the start)

Comment: Right, I found the way to convert a Blob to base64 and as you mentioned, it's through FileReader.... which is apparently going to be deprecated along with the whole FileSystem api! Anyway, where I to use a part of the FileSystem api, I could at this point make my whole life easier by just getting everything done with it rather than showing giant strings down IndexedDB's throat. I am astonished by how convoluted this whole thing is: "Downloading a file, storing it locally for offline use".

Comment: A few years ago, _JavaScript_ couldn't do any of that so it is moving forwards. Where did you read about these things being depreciated though? Half of them aren't even fully implemented/out of draft yet

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html

Comment: I found this interesting article about local filesystem storing. https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit/